# Why does my code reset when using addEventListener with "click"?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, createelement

I'm trying to implement addEventListener so that every time I click a button a new LI will be added to my HTML with text.
For some reason the LI is added for a fraction of a second and then disappears.
I have implemented a form with user input similarly while listening to 'submit', but when I try to do the same with 'click' it won't work.
I can use the 'submit' option but I'm trying to understand why 'click' is not working.
I'd appreciate any help.
Thank you!

```
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('#searchBtn');
const list = document.querySelector('#uls');

searchBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    const movieName = document.createElement('LI');
    const text = "works";
    list.append(movieName);
    movieName.innerHTML = text;  
    }
)
```

Comment: _"For some reason the LI is added for a fraction of a second and then disappears."_ - the most common reason for that would be that you accidentally submitted a form, which will then load the page again. But your snippet above lacks context for us to be able to tell what exactly the situation is. Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, when asking this kind of question.

Comment: Why do you write li in all caps?

Comment: @Geshode probably because the value of `element.tagName` is returned in upper case within HTML documents, even though `document.createElement` accepts lower cased tag names.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the attribute `type="button"` on the button element declaration in HTML.

```
 <button id="searchBtn" type="button">Search</button>
```

This prevents the button submitting the form (which resets the page), *because the default button type is "submit"*.

If you never want the form to be submitted, try removing the opening and closing `form` tags, or supply a submit event handler that calls `event.stopPropagation` and/or `event.preventDefault`.